# Vue.js + Webpack multiple style tas output

Tags: css, webpack, less, vue.js

I have several vue.js components, written in single page component format.

For each .vue file, I have less written specific for that page.

After bundling, I have several style tags, which populate the global style space. Thus, some of my classes are overlapping on different pages.

[image: Head]

Is this the intended functionality with vue.js and webpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behaviour for [vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) (which is the main plugin in the vue-webpack template).

However, if you want to you can extract all CSS into one file:

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

---

```
// webpack.config.js
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  // other options...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
    ]
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css"),
      // you can also include <style lang="less"> or other langauges
      less: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("css!less")
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
  ]
}
```

Check out the docs of [vue-loader](http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html) regarding extraction.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I realize we're 1.5 years past. Webpack 4 is out and it doesn't allow the vue object in the root export like you have. How does this work now?

Comment: Should use vue-style-loader nowadays, take a look here: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html