# how to extract vue files style into one seperate style.css file

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-loader, extracttextwebpackplugin

I'm using vue-loader and by default for each vue files you have one style tag in your view which is not a good thing,
according to vue-loader documentation i can do this

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html
my webpack-config.js file

```
   var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // this one extracts css files that imported to styles.css
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader' ,
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      },
      {
         // and this dude here extracts component's styles into styles.css
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
                  css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: 'css-loader',
          fallback: 'vue-style-loader' 
        })
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
       test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
       loader: 'url-loader?importLoaders=1&limit=100000'
     }
    ]
  },

      plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

but this code is not working at all and behavior is the same .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is one issue simillar to your problem, check it out

*Url(https://stackoverflow.com/a/40199096/6381510)*

but this better

```
 less: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              loader: 'css-loader!less-loader?indentedSyntax',
              fallbackLoader: 'vue-style-loader',
            }),
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Deathangel908/a9fa7f805623dee097f54b2da127819c `ExtractTextPlugin` doesn't have those options, it throws `false` from `throw new _ValidationError2.default(ajv.errors, name);` How comes this works?

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined and imported ExtracTextPlugin?

```
  plugins: [
   new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
  ],
```

If you can put here the whole code would be great.

Comment: I have updated my question and also i noticed it's not working as well wehen i', using less

Comment: @moeinrahimi Use the Davod answer, you are trying to compile less, but your ExtracPlugin has css defined instead.