# Vuejs: Includes css file in webpack minified css

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

in my vuejs project i want to include my personnal css files to the generated minified css file generated from the styles in *.vue files

In App.vue i have:

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import '/static/css/AdminLTE.min.css';
  @import '/static/css/style.css';
  @import '/static/js/plugins/pace/pace.min.css';
</style>
```

And i use ExtractTextPlugin to extract and minify styles in *.vue files:

```
 // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: {
        safe: true
      }
    }),
```

So i my website the app.conbtenthash.css file from the plugin and the three files i import.
But is there anyway to include my three imported file in the app css file ?

Than you !

Answer (score 0):

Docs: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/configurations/extract-css.html

Similar questions:
[Vue.js + Webpack multiple style tas output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40005832/vue-js-webpack-multiple-style-tas-output/40199096) |
[how to extract vue files style into one seperate style.css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864750/how-to-extract-vue-files-style-into-one-seperate-style-css-file)

So you should specify single filename in ExtractTextPlugin

```
new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css")
```